# How do I create a Route that matches parameters when they contain slashes (/)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have only a route in my ASP.NET MVC App:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post",
    "post/{url}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post" }
);
```

When I go to `/post/MyTestBlahBlah` it matches correctly, and calls Blog.Post(url).

However, when I go to `/post/2010/03/MyTestBlahBlah` I get a 404.

How do I make the route match urls even with there are slashes in them?

**Note:** MY URLs are not fixed as /year/month/post, they can be in *any* format, which is why I want to match *all* URLs. I need it to be capture and passed into the controller (as opposed to using "*") to aid testing - I do not want the Controller to read the URL from the Response object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, I would add a new route **before** that route described there:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post_Verbose",
    "post/{year}/{month}/{url}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post" });
```

Or simply:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post",
    "post/{*url}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post" });
```

Comment: My URLs are not fixed in this format, which is why I need to match them all. I don't actually have "/post/" at the start, but I thought adding this would avoid people telling me to use "*", because I need the URL to be passed into the Action.

Comment: The problem with catch all routes is they tend to break a lot of specific things. What's the purpose of passing in a whole url, would it not make sense to take advantage of the routing system to separate url parts into associated parameters?

Comment: I am taking advantage of the routing system - I will have a number of routes (such as /archive/{year}/{month} and /{page}), however my posts can use any remaining format, which means they must be a catchall (and will be the last route).

Comment: I just realised I mentioned having a "single route" in my question. I realise why it looked like I was ignoring routing - it's actually just because I was trying to get this route working first, as the other routes are trivial. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @Matthew Since I don't get rep for my own answer (and can't mark it for days), if you edit your answer to include "{*url}" I'll mark it as the answer and remove mine. Thanks for trying to help :-)

Comment: My answer wouldn't appear at the top of the list anyway, so it's better for people searching to have the correct answer at the top. We're doing other people a favour :D

Comment: @Danny Yeah...it's for everyone, promise... *whistles*

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution [here](http://blog.marcmezzacca.com/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-3-routes-allow-arbitrary-number-of-slashes-with-catch-all/). You need to put a "*" in front of the paramter name (`{*url}`). Ironically, the first thing I tried was `{url*}`!

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post",
    "post/{*url}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post" }
);
```